# Executar insert em Migrations Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em ASP.NET MVC com Entity Framework Code First.
Já mapeei o banco e gerei o primeiro Migrations, minha dúvida é:
tem como executar um `insert` logo após a criação de uma tabela?
Exemplo:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Permissao",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Descricao = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 350),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
    //e aqui executar os insert
    //exemplo: insert into Permissao (id, descricao) values(1, "Administrador");
    //insert into Permissao (id, descricao) values(2, "Professor");
    //insert into Permissao (id, descricao) values(3, "Aluno");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, use o método `Seed` gerado em `Migrations\Configuratiom.cs`:

```
    protected override void Seed(MeuProjeto.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
```

O `Seed` é executado ao final do processo de aplicação das migrações.